# SQL check if data is sampled

Tags: mysql

I have a database with data that has x different filters and an angle between -180 to 180. I'd like to check if a certain filter has atleast one datapoint in a range of 5 degrees. So yes or 1 if there is a datapoint between -180 and -175 for filter 1.

I've managed to count the amount of items per filter in total

```
'SELECT COUNT(data),filt FROM database GROUP BY filt ORDER BY filt'
```

This gives:

```
(11093, 'R1')
(24067, 'R2')
(12234, 'R3')
(4, 'RH2')
(12888, 'SIC')
(7557, 'SI')
(1570, 'SI2')
(2922, 'SI3')
```

But I have no idea how to take the next step

Comment: `max(case when filt='filtervalue' and datapoint between -180 and -175 then 1 end)` conditional aggregation with a max?  assuming 'filtervalue' is set to the filter you want to check and datapoint is the column name containing the degree.  question is unclear however as we don't know all the field names of table 'database' odd table name...

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that relies on the fact that the points are always in the range -180 to +180

```
SELECT distinct ( (id -180) div -355) as d, filt
FROM database
WHERE ( (id -180) div -355) = 1
ORDER BY filt;
```

The point is that only values -175 to -180 will give d=1.